# How to turn 3 lists into an ordered dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have searched but I can't find anything that works... I was hoping that someone might be able to help me out.

I have 3 lists:

```
a = [(1), (7), (3), (1)]

b = [(2), (4), (7), (4)]

c = [(8), (1), (3), (3)]
```

I was then thinking that I could turn them into tuples:

```
ab = [(1,2), (7,4), (3,7), (1,4)]

bc = [(1,2,8), (7,4,1), (3,7,3), (1,4,3)]
```

Then I could finally turn it into an ordered `dict` of unique tuples where the first element from each tuple is the key and in the case of repeated key the next largest element in the tuple breaks the tie:

(I am not sure but this code might work):

```
print(dict(sorted(ab, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))))
```

leaving me with `({1:4, 3:7, 7:4})`

And also somehow print the match in `bc`.
To make it clearer:

It prints:

```
1,4,3 # not 1,2,8 as  4 > 2
3,7,3
7,4,1
```

By getting the `(1,4)` from the tuple `ab` and finding it in `bc`, then printing `bc`.

Comment: Not sure what your question actually is?

Comment: Please edit the question to show your expected output.

Comment: I just have, hopefully my edit has helped. I accidentally pressed 'ask' before I had finished the question. Sorry. @MartinEvans

Comment: why do you have parens around the numbers?

Comment: Are you supposed to have one element  tuples or what is in your lists? Also how does `({1:4, 3:7, 7:4})` come about?

Comment: I was trying to have in ab the things in a and b, and for the things in bc to be the things in a, b and c

Comment: I am sorry but I am completely lost, can you just add what you expect as output

Comment: For it to print:

(1,4,3) (3,7,3) (7,4,1)

Comment: Why is 1,2,8 gone? Because of the second element?

Comment: Because when you put it in a dictionary it can only have 1  with the key of 1 whatever the variable and when it is put in a dictionary it keeps the (1,4) bit and forgets the (1,2)

Comment: Yes but why does it forget the 1,2 and not 1,4

Comment: Good question, I will check

Comment: I have just noticed that if the dictionary is like `mydict = {1:2, 1:4}` it will save as {1:4} however if it is saved as `mydict = {1:4, 1:2}` it will instead save it as {1:2}. I am currently looking for the dict to be sorted so the info will be put in such a way it outputs the 1:4 instead of the 1:2. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld, then my answer is what you want

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding what a Python dictionary is use for. In Python, standard dictionaries are not sorted and they're not used to produce sorted output. They are only used as a lookup system to cross-reference two pieces of information. For your task, maybe you would be happy with `sorted(zip(a, b, c))`?

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham your answer really helps

Comment: @mfripp, an OrderedDict does keep order and just sorting is not going to remove duplicates based on the first element of each tuple.

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld, no worries, you're welcome.

Comment: Just a shame my question is on -2 :-( @PadraicCunningham

Comment: @RulerOfTheWorld, I edited the question to hopefully make it more clear what you were asking, maybe someone will offset the downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  want to keep the tuples with the highest second elements for repeating keys where the keys are the first element of each tuple after zipping your lists, just sorting will mean you keep that last seen/higher value:

```
from collections import  OrderedDict

print(list(OrderedDict((sub[0], sub) for sub in sorted(zip(a, b, c))).values()))
[(1, 4, 3), (3, 7, 3), (7, 4, 1)]
```

When you sort:

```
In [8]: sorted(zip(a, b, c))
Out[8]: [(1, 2, 8), (1, 4, 3), (3, 7, 3), (7, 4, 1)]
```

You get the "higher values" later in the list so by default we will always keep the value for repeating keys that is the greatest.

Comment: You could also use something like this: `abc = sorted(zip(a, b, c)); filtered = {a: (a, b, c) for (a, b, c) in abc}; print sorted(filtered.values())`

Comment: @mfripp, you could but why sort twice when once will do?

Comment: I think I just liked the idea of sticking with built-in types and using a dictionary comprehension, and I had a vague suspicion that OrderedDict would be sorting entries as I added them. I should have checked the docs, and I would have found that OrderedDict is ordered by when the entries are added, not lexicographically, so it doesn't add an extra sort. By the way, isn't list(dict.values()) the same as dict.values()?

Comment: @mfripp, depends on the python version, .values returns a dictview object  in python3 so you need to call list so I just use it to cover both scenarios

Comment: Padraic, thanks. There's something new to learn every day!